# Getting data from forked children

Tags: php, pcntl

I am playing with [pcntl_fork()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) in PHP.

I took the class that is written in the second comment, and tried to send data to it - which seems to work fine.

Now I did some processing on that data, and would like to receive some results in my parent process.

Does anyone know how this can be done ? The only way I can think of doing this is to store the information in the database and/or other storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked with pcntl fork in a number of projects i do not believe there is any way to send data back to the parent process directly. You would be able to do this via the database as you have already mentioned however you may be better off using PHP's shared memory components (http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) or memcache for this purpose.

Can you elaborate on what you are doing, it may be that you can avoid this requirement.

Comment: I ended up doing this script in python and reduced the run time of the script from 3 minutes to ~20 seconds :) Thank you for the answer